# Error : BLD00102 : No such file or directory 'VERSION' with Visual Studio Tools for Apache Cordova

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-cordova

I'm using the Tools for Apache Cordova in Visual Studio 2013.
Upon building my project, I get the following error:

> **Error : BLD00102 : No such file or directory 'VERSION'**

The weird thing is that this project ran successfully already.
Besides, ever since I got this error, it also happens on all my other projects.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the **Cordova cache became corrupted**, causing the build to fail on all Cordova projects.

Luckily, the **Tools for Apache Cordova** provide an easy solution to such problems:

- From the Menu in Visual Studio, choose **`Tools` -> `Options`**
- Expand **`Tools for Apache Cordova`** and click **`Cordova Tools`**
- Hit the button **`Clear Cordova Cache`**
- **`Build`** the project again and Visual Studio will freshly install the needed packages and compile just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the bin and bld folder from project folder. and rebuild agian. it will fix the issue immediately